# Center logo in html

Tags: html, css, image, header, alignment

I have an logo in the header of the page and I want to make in centered.
This is my html:

```css
body {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
header {
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #b5b5b5;
}
.logo {
  width: 250px;
  height: 150px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="logo-row">
        <img src="resources/img/logo.png" alt="logo" class="logo">
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a width to the `logo-row` class and use `margin: 0 auto`.

```css
body {
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

header {
    margin-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #b5b5b5;
}

.logo-row {
    width: 250px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.logo {
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="logo-row">
        <img src="resources/img/logo.png" alt="logo" class="logo">
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
```

Answer (score 2):

Giving `text-align: center` to the `.logo-row`, you may achieve the desired output:

```css
header {
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #b5b5b5;
}
.logo-row{
  text-align: center;
}
.logo {
  width: 250px;
  height: 150px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
  <header>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="logo-row">
        <img src="resources/img/logo.png" alt="logo" class="logo">
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
```

Comment: I think there is no need of display: inline-block; in this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Add a new CSS rule for the div containing your image:

```
.logo-row {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```css
body {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
header {
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #b5b5b5;
}
.logo {
  width: 250px;
  height: 150px;
  text-align: center;
}
.logo-row {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="logo-row">
        <img src="resources/img/logo.png" alt="logo" class="logo">
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
```

Comment: @RichardHamilton - On what element?

Answer (score 1):

Add this code to your CSS Section

```
.logo-row{ text-align: center; }
```

Comment: Before anyone chooses to [recommend deletion](http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/11120945) of this post, this is a valid attempted answer. This post should not have been flagged and should not be recommended for deletion in the LQPRQ. See: [You're doing it wrong: A plea for sanity in the Low Quality Posts queue](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287563) and [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370)

Answer (score 1):

Add the following **CSS** rule for the class applied to the `img` element (in your case .logo).

```
.logo {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```css
img {

display:block;
margin-right:auto;
margin-left:auto;

}
```